# Is there a way to SQL ORDER BY column ASCENDING with certain results above the ORDER BY?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a 100ish row lookup table that I'm using to generate a vertical check box list on a web page. Very simple query to get the results:

```
SELECT servicetype FROM XXX
```

I want to know if there is a way to ORDER BY the column but have certain known values appear on top of the list out of the sort?  Something like (and I don't even know how to write this psuedocode but...)

```
SELECT servicetype FROM XXX
ORDER BY servicetype ASC 
WITH servicetype IN ('Personal', 'Juggling') ON TOP
```

So that my list would look something like:

```
Juggling         - On top regardless of ORDER BY
Personal         - On top regardless of ORDER BY
Anteating        - Everything else is ORDER BY
Barflying
Beafeating
Carswatting
etc...
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `order by case when servicetype = 'personal' or servicetype = 'juggling' then 1 else 2 end`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use:

```
SELECT servicetype FROM XXX
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN servicetype IN ('Personal', 'Juggling') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC
  , servicetype ASC
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT servicetype 
FROM XXX
order by case when servicetype = 'Juggling' then 'a'
              when servicetype = 'Personal' then 'b'
              else servicetype
         end
```

Comment: servicetype = 'abc' :)

Comment: Fair enough @lad2025 though that'd be highly unexpected from the sample data.